# Will Confidential Transactions allow us to reuse addresses safely?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, privacy

It is often said that, due to the natural transparency of the blockchain, one should have a multi-address wallet and try to not reuse addresses, so that the user's transactions are not so easily revealed.

Now, it seems at some point we will have the [Confidential Transactions feature](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt) implemented in Core. So, when this moment arrives, will we be able to reuse addresses? Will it be safe to use a mono-address wallet?

Answer (score 6):

My understanding of confidential transactions is that it only hides the amounts, not the addresses involved (someone please let me know if this is not the case).

Since only the amount is hidden, reusing the same address would still connect your various transactions together, linking them as likely involving the same user.

Comment: you mean because they would know who are you transacting with? or because you can always know the total balance of an address regardless of CT usage?

Comment: You can't know the balance of an address if CT is being used, but you can still know if it's being used or not.

Comment: ok, that's good enough for me, thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. Don't forget that ole green check mark if this answered your Q ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advice that. That still leaves a huge amount of meta data visible to everyone.

Also, why would you. HD wallets are very well supported these days.

Comment: what does HD stand for?

Comment: Hierarchical deterministic wallet.